# Escaping special characters in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle11g

Is there an easy way in Oracle to escape special characters in a SQL statement? (i.e. %, &, ')  I saw this [link](http://orafaq.com/faq/how_does_one_escape_special_characters_when_writing_sql_queries) in regard to manually escaping characters, but I thought Oracle may have provided an easier way to do so.

Note:  I'm generating dynamic SQL select statements through an ORM.

Comment: The only thing that needs "escaping" is the single quote inside a character literal. None of the others you mention are "special characters" that need escaping.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Actually the percentage and underscore are special characters when using the WHERE .. LIKE clause.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If using bind variables and ORM, embedded single quotes and ampersands should be handed automatically; those are special characters in SQL*Plus or SQL*Developer.

To use LIKE where looking for the literal characters % and _ (not their multi- and single-character wildcard versions), you'd use the `escape` clause of the `like` condition:

```
select * from my_table where some_text like '/%%' escape '/';
```

will only return the rows where some_text begins with a percent sign.

Answer (score 2):

It seems you're looking for something like the command SET DEFINE OFF, which you can run and it affects the whole SQL session. This command, however, only prevents Oracle from giving special meaning to the ampersand character. It doesn't affect other special characters such as the single quote.

A couple of links to additional information regarding escaping characters follow:

https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2256637

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/text.920/a96518/cqspcl.htm

Comment: The ampersand is recognized by the SQL*Plus client. It's not a special character for the actual database server.

Answer (score 0):

here's the definitive answer page on tech on the net. Even provides examples and exercises

http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/like.php